# Error when trying to write out a series of elements using map.filter to filter my results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-component

I have this component that creates a collection of  tags for use in another components  element.

I'm trying to write out the options based on a filter so that it looks something like this:

```
<optgroup label "PlayerOnly"></optgroup>
<option value ="1" label="Fighter" />
<option value ="2" label="Wizard" />
<option value ="3" label="Theif" />
<optgroup label "MonsterOnly"></optgroup>
<option value ="4" label="Troll" />
<option value ="5" label="Giant" />
<option value ="6" label="Goblin" />
```

It groups them by a field called groupById.

But when I try to run it, I just get this error:

```
Syntax error: Binding invalid left-hand side in function parameter list
```

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const OptionList = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://localhost:44376/api/characters',
            );
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <optgroup label="PlayerOnly"></optgroup>
            {data.filter((item => item.groupById == 7) => (
            <option key={index} value={item.id} label={item.name} />
            ))}
            <optgroup label="MonsterOnly"></optgroup>
            {data.filter((item => item.groupById == 11) => (
            <option key={index} value={item.id} label={item.name} />
            ))}
        </>

    );
}
export default OptionList;
```

Comment: The problem is `<>` and that error is coming from babel parser. I think you need special plugin to support that. Try importing `Fragment` instead and replace `<>` with `<Fragment>`.

Comment: @norbertpy I don't think that's the problem becuase I can get the component to work when I use data.map like this: {data.map((item, index) => do stuff

Comment: Then what Paul has down there is your problem. The `filter` returns an array so you need to `map` again to generate the `<option>` elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
{data.filter(item => item.groupById == 7).map((item, index) => (
  <option key={index} value={item.id} label={item.name} />
)}
```

Try this, you were passing a function as the left hand parameter to filter rather than an iterable.